# Hide form submit button until hidden field is populated using HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, submit

I have a Google geocoding form which, once the user presses enter, populates a mainly hidden form - split into street address, town and postal code but with a visible submit button (for when the address is valid).

In the UK, a valid address is found once the postcode is found.

So, to confirm that the address is a bona fide one, once the hidden postcode field is populated, I wish only then to display the submit button.

I wish to use standard Javascript on the HTML page to make this work. Any ideas?

Comment: You may want to add a code snippet to illustrate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add a 'change' event listener to the zipcode field

```js
document.getElementById("zip").addEventListener("change", function() {
    if (this.value != null && this.value != "") {
     document.getElementById("test").style.display = "block";
    }
});
```

```css
#test {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="zip"/>
<button id="test">
test
</button>
```